# Freecad not working on my raspbian!

Tags: raspbian, software-installation, pi-4, crash

I just installed free cad on raspbian from repo . Then after the installation was complete when I preseed the freecad icon from menu it is opening. But when I am pressing new project the software is closing. 
Then I tried it from terminal. Things are same there too. How to fix this problem?
I am using Raspberry pi4 4GB.

Comment: You're not the ojlly one: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=244151 . There are some links in that topic that may be worthwhile checking out.